# Spring Cloud Dataflow send buffered messages to output channel

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have a filter which buffers rejected messages. I would like to send these buffered messages to the output channel once my predicate is satisfied:

```
public class MyFilter implements MessageSelector {

    private Buffer buff;

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean accept(final Message<?> message) {
        if (isAcceptable(message))) {
            for (final Message<?> msg : buff.getBuffered()) {
                // accept these as well
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            buff.put(message);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I accept the buffered messages? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that an [aggregator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#aggregator) with a custom `ReleaseStrategy` would be a good approach. When the release strategy releases the group, if the output processor (`@Aggregator` method when configuring that way) returns a collection of `Message<?>` they will be released as individual messages.

When using Java configuration, you might find it simpler to use the Java DSL `.aggregate(...)` function than creating `@Bean`s.

There is currently a [pull request](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/aggregator/pull/1) for an aggregator app starter.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Thanks for the method tip, I prefer `@Bean`s, I just personally find it cleaner when I have a lot of stuff going on since I package more Applications into a single Boot app and `@Configuration` can get pretty big.

Comment: As you can see in the PR, the aggregator factory bean can help too.